# C# with MySQL connector - access denied

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, connection-string, mysql-connector

I have a remote hosted website with a `MySQL` database.

I am trying to access that database from a small `C#` program.

**What I've tried**:

- Referencing the MySQL DLL in the project
- Using MySQL connection strings
- Disabling my firewall
- Adding my IP address to the `Remote MySQL Databases` in the site's cPanel

**What I'm getting**:

- *Access denied for user blabla@mycomputerip* in the Visual Studio console

**What boggles my mind**:

- How can I find out if my webhosting service allows remote connections to the DB?
- Do I really need to connect with PuTTy to the server and tweak the configs?
- ^ if so, do I even have access to do that?

**LATER EDIT:**

- Interesting enough. If I do

  ```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
  ```

  it throws me this:

  ```
  #1045 - Access denied for user 'blabla'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
  ```

  Common sense should tell you that my username is not actually 'blabla'.

**LATER LATER EDIT:**

I don't have privileges to CREATE USER, nor do I have SSH access via PuTTy or so. 
Does this basically mean that it's my hosting's fault that I can't connect from a remote location to the DB?

Comment: Are you running on a VPS or on a shared host?  If on a shared host, the MySQL server is probably shared as well, so you wouldn't be able to grant privs on everything since you don't have access to everything yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the users in your mysql database.  A couple things to check:

1. With cPanel on shared hosting, if you create a user named `blah` the actual name of the user in mysql is often `unixusername_blah`.  This is done automatically to prevent MySQL user name conflicts between different cPanel accounts sharing the same MySQL server.
2. With MySQL you can define which hosts a user is allowed to connect from.  Is the new user you defined allowed to connect from your IP?

ETA:

Might want to have a look at the permissions for that user account and make sure appropriate permissions are granted.  You can do this by running the following in phpMyAdmin or at the console:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'something_root'@'localhost'
```

And compare the grants you see there to what you get here:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'something_root'@'%'
```

Finally, depending on your hosting environment you may not have permissions to create new users or expand their privileges enough to be able to do this.  This would be particularly likely if you have a shared hosting account.

Comment: The username for the DB is **censored**_root, which I've created a while ago. I use this use to connect to the DB in my PHP application, which is uploaded on the website. I've added the `%` wild card, and now it just says `Access denied for **censored**_root@%`.

Comment: @GGeorge - Updated my answer.  Could be that while the user with the `%` wildcard now exists, it doesn't have the right grants.

Comment: Show grants for 'something_root' throws me access denied. BUT, Show grants for 'something' actually returns me a result. I'm really confused, cause that suggests that I'm logged in with 'something' and not 'something_root'.

Comment: I feel like I'm lacking serious theoretical basis with this whole MySQL access stuff.

Comment: @GGeorge - based on your last edit, I'd say you probably can't do what you want to here.  You might need to switch from a shared hosting environment to a VPS where you have a bit more control over the server.

Comment: Yes Eric, you are right. Your answer was the starting point for finding the problem. You should add another edit to your answer, maybe it will help others. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find out if my webhosting service allows remote connections?

It's better ask your whebhosting proveder, some allows remote connections, other no.
If they allow remote connections you may have to configure which hosts a user is allowed to connect from or, add a wildcard % to allow connections from any host.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your hosting service allows connecting to its database server from outside its network.
Some hosting companies like GoDaddy, by default, don't allow this.

Also, you need to create a database user and assign permissions to it, through your preferred database administration tool.

Answer (score 0):

reset mysql user password and then try again

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html